# [Angular UI-Router]: Refer to named view of current state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

As described by the UI-Router documentation you could use [relative and absolute names to refer to a named view](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names).

In short:

```
.state('contacts.detail', {
  views: {
    // Absolutely targets the 'content' view in root unnamed state.
    'content@': {},
    // Relatively targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
    'detail': {}
    // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
    // It's the absolute version of the relative one above.
    'detail@contacts': {}
  }
});
```

So relative names target views of the *parent* state.

To target a named view of the *current* state you have to use the absolute name like this:

```
.state('contacts.detail', {
  views: {
    'info@contacts.detail': {}
  }
});
```

**The question is:**
Is it possible to target a named view of the *current* state with a relative name?
OR
Is there any shortcut to use in absolute names for the current state so you don't have to write the full name of the state behind the `@`-symbol?
Something like `info@.` instead of `info@contacts.detail`.

Comment: No, but you could file an issue requesting that feature.  In ui-router 1.0, 1) the unnamed view is called `$default` and 2) you can traverse ui-views.  So if you know the view in the parent is the unnamed view, you can use `{ "$default.info": ... }`

Comment: I implemented this for next version of `ui-router-core`: https://github.com/ui-router/core/issues/25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of angular-ui-router  `1.0.0-rc.1` you cannot easily target a view on the current state.

However, the next version will allow using `"view@."` to target the `" from the current state.

See https://github.com/ui-router/core/issues/25 (and the test: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/commit/6f2f4ab55475cd8fb533e53414a64574226be502)